# Apache doesn't autostart because vpn isn't up yet

Tags: apache-2.2, vpn, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD8 server, and VPN connection to my ISP. I use mpd5 and it works fine.
Also I have an Apache server whch works fine, if I start it manually, after VPN is get up. 
But when I add it to rc.conf autostart, it fail to start, saying

```
(49) can't assign requested address: make_sock could not bind to address
```

I suppose it's because VPN isn't up yet and no IP address assigned to the interface which i set in the `Listen` directive in the httpd.conf.
If i set Listen to the existing 127.0.0.1, it fail to serve wan requests.

Is there a solution, either to delay apache autostart or configure it some different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address is optional. Just set something like

```
Listen 80
```

And it will bind to port 80 on all interfaces.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/bind.html

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am just blind. I tried this before, but it didn't work because I havent /etc/hosts record yet, and it failed for another reason. I just have to be more persistent :) Thanks again!